# Multiple Pipe Recursive Handing in c

Tags: c, recursion, process, pipe, fork

I want to handle multiple pipes in c via a recursive function. I could not figure it what is wrong. Whether I did not hook up the pipes properly or I left some process hanging. Please give some advice.
Assume: token[0] = "ls"; token[1] = "|"; token[2] = "sort"; token[3] = "|"; token[4] = "more";

```
int pipeExecution(char *token[]) {
    int isPipe = 0;
    int fds[2] = {0};
    pid_t pid;
    for (int i = 0; token[i] != NULL; i++) {
        if (strcmp(token[i], "|") == 0) {
            isPipe = 1;
            token[i] = NULL;
            if (pipe(fds) < 0) {
                perror("Can not pipe\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            pid = fork();
            if (pid < 0) {
                perror("Can not fork() **1\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            } else {
                if (pid > 0) {
                    pid = fork();
                    if (pid < 0) {
                        perror("Can not fork() **2\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    } else {
                        if (pid > 0) { // parent
                            wait(NULL);
                        } else { // child 2 - excuse the command after a "|"
                            close(fds[1]); // does not write to pipe
                            if (dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO) < 0) {
                                perror("Can not dup2()\n");
                                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                            }
                            printf("execute tokens after |\n");
                            pipeExecution(token + (i + 1));
                        }
                    }
                } else { // child 1 - excuse the command before a "|"
                    printf("execute tokens before |\n");
                    close(fds[0]); // does not read from pipe
                    if (dup2(fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO) < 0) {
                        perror("Can not dup2()\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    execvp(token[0], token);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isPipe == 0) {
        perror(token[0]);
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("Can not fork()\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (pid > 0) {
            wait(NULL);
        } else {
            execvp(token[0], token);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `token[0] = "ls"; token[1] = "|"; token[2] = "sort"; token[3] = "|"; token[4] = "more";`?

Comment: Also, what happens when you run it?

Comment: Yes. It should be token[0] = "ls"; token[1] = "|"...

Comment: The I/O of the very parent process is wrong, and it does not write to the intended output. Base on the output, I also think the there are a few processes do not terminate.